# Failed to ugrade a Spring Boot app to Flyway 7.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to upgrade my Spring Boot 2.3.4 app to use Flyway 7.0.0 (the latest version). Previously it was using Flyway 6.5.6. The relevant entries in `build.gradle` are shown below.

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    flywayVersion = "7.0.0" // changed from 6.5.6
  }
}

plugins {
  id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "${flywayVersion}"
}

dependencies {
  implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:${flywayVersion}"
}

flyway {
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/postgres"
  user = "postgres"
  password = "secret"
}
```

The following error occurs when I start the app e.g. with `./gradlew bootRun`

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt
> was made from the following location:
>
> ```
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65)
> ```
>
> The following method did not exist:
>
> ```
> 'int org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate()'
> ```
>
> The method's class, org.flywaydb.core.Flyway, is available from the
> following locations:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/Users/antonio/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/7.0.0/623494c303c62080ca1bc5886098ee65d1a5528a/flyway-core-7.0.0.jar!/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.class
> ```
>
> The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
>
> ```
> org.flywaydb.core.Flyway: file:/Users/antonio/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/7.0.0/623494c303c62080ca1bc5886098ee65d1a5528a/flyway-core-7.0.0.jar
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a
> single, compatible version of org.flywaydb.core.Flyway

Comment: please provide the github code base to check the issue.

Comment: @AnishB. https://github.com/flyway/flyway

Comment: can you provide your project through github ?

Comment: @AnishB. I cannot

Comment: OK ! I see. No issue

Comment: In Flyway 7 we made breaking changes to the api, one of which was changing migrate() to return information about what was migrated, instead of just an int. As a result it will not be compatible with spring boot until a new version of springboot is released compiled against this new version.

I would advise raising an issue on the spring boot github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, see Philip's comment on your question.

Flyway 7.x.x is not currently compatible with Spring Boot 2.3.4

Temporary solution is to just downgrade to Flyway 6.5.7 (the last 6.x.x version) until Spring Boot 2.3.5 is released.

Read more and follow the issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23514

Support for Flyway's new configuration options: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23579

Answer (score 9):

In Flyway 7 the signature of `migrate` changed.

To get Flyway 7.x.x working with Spring Boot 2.3.x you can provide a custom FlywayMigrationStrategy implementation, which calls the the right `migrate` method.

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationStrategy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FlywayMigrationStrategyImpl implements FlywayMigrationStrategy {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23514

Answer (score 1):

downgrade to Flyway 6.5.7 works.